# How to create a hierarchical query as a materilized view with refresh on commit in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, materialized-views, connect-by, hierarchical-query

Could anyone please tell me if there is a possibility to create a hierarchical query in oracle 10g as a materialized view with REFRESH ON COMMIT?

I tried using CONNECT_BY but this doesn't work with REFRESH ON COMMIT.

Are there any other possibilities to get the view automatically refreshed when the underlying data changes?

Or may be there is an alternative to CONNECT_BY which works with REFRESH ON COMMIT?

Thanks in advance for any hints or help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really doubt that you'll be able to get this functionality. I think that the best you can hope for is to be able to define a materialized view that optimises the hierarchical query, for example by basing the MV on an underlying table that is actually index-organised or hash clustered on the parent_id column.